# How to make a game menu screen (with no UI)

Tags: python

I am making a simple maths game and want to make it so once you complete or fail a section of the game you will be redirected back to the menu screen where you can check what you're score was from that section of the game was.

I already have score counters working under each game section.

I've basically tried just printing my variable for the score from the menu screen but it doesn't work because it isn't defined.

````
import time
import random
from subprocess import call


def menuScreen():
    print("Welcome to Jamal's Master Math Game! \n [1]To play the game, type 1. \n [2]To check your score, type 2.")
    print(" [3]To exit now, type exit.")
    userInput = input("")
    if userInput == "2":
        print("You're score is" + score)
    if userInput == "3":
        exit()
    elif userInput == "1":
        print("Please choose one of the four game options.")
        print("[1]Addition" + "\n" + "[2]Multiplication" + "\n" + "[3]Subtraction" + "\n" + "[4]Division")
        userInput = int(input())
        if userInput == 1:
             addition()
         elif userInput == 2:
             multiplication()


def addition():
```
        Random = 1
        Random_two = 2
        lit = (Random + Random_two)
        answer = str(lit)
        score = 0
        while answer == str(lit):
            for x in range(1):
                Random = random.randint(1, 101)
                Random_two = random.randint(1, 101)
            lit = (Random + Random_two)
            answer = str(lit)
            print("What is " + str(Random) + " + " + str(Random_two) + "?")
            userInput = input()
            if userInput == (str(lit)):
                if score >= 5:
                    print("Okay, so you can do easy mathematics.")
                    print("Time for the real challenge.")
                    print("Do you want to know your score?")
                    userInput = input()
                    myList = ["okay", "Okay", "sure", "Sure", "ye", "Ye", "yes", "Yes"]
                    if userInput in myList:
                        print("Your score = " + str(score))
                    else:
                        print("Okay, Goodbye.")
                        menuScreen()
                    break
                print("Next question.")
                answer = str(lit)
                score += 1
            else:
                print("That is incorrect. \nGame Over.")
                menuScreen()
    else:
        print("Try again.")
        menuScreen()


def multiplication():
```

#where the game actually starts
menuScreen()
````

I expect the final code to print the previous score value when the user asks for it in the menu screen.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this... one would be to return the score from the function, and keep track of it in menuscreen(), or make a global variable for score, and store the values in there... This would ensure that whenever you update score, the global variable also changes, and you can access it from any method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comment there are two general ways to have a variable available in two different methods.

1. As you call `addition()` from your `menuScreen()` you could have `score` as a return value and therefore use it in `menuScreen()` as well.
2. You define `score` as a global variable and therefore have it available in all methods.

Comment: Thanks, I used global and everything worked as I wanted it to.